# Does a large black area in live view mean my camera is terminally broken?

Tags: repair, nikon-d3300

I bought a new Nikon D3300, and used it twice to test taking photos. After a week, I opened my camera again to take photos, but the live view display was half black and half normal; the black isn't completely black - I could still see some of the environment, but it's *very* dark.

The camera is brand new and it hasn't been dropped or had any bad abuse which makes me wonder why this has happened. The settings screen works fine, but when I switch to live view the screen is split:

[image: Nikon D3300 with faulty live view display]

Is there anything I can do, or should I send this camera to Nikon to be repaired?

Comment: I think this is pretty clearly a case for Nikon service.

Comment: Do the photos come out, or do they also display the artifact? This doesn't change the advice to contact the service center, but will help narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: yes.the photo comes out.but it looks exactly like this photo i upoloaded.its half black and half normal.

Comment: If it's only a week old, can you go back to the retailer and exchange for a new one?

Comment: What was the light level (in general terms) when you took the picture? (bright sunlight outdoors, dim lighting at night indoors, etc.) - FYI I'm trying to figure out why the ISO is so high.

Comment: "opened my camera"? There's your problem :)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like either the sensor is broken, or possibly something is wrong in its data connection to the rest of the camera.  Either way, there is nothing you can do about this.

Since you *just* bought the camera, you may be able to return it, but that will depend on the seller's policies and perhaps on local law. Otherwise, call Nikon and send the camera in for repair or exchange. There should be no problem at all with this being covered by Nikon under warranty.

Comment: well if for any reason the sensor is broken then its very sad because i didnt touch the camera at all.its pretty new i just bought it.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate, but manufacturing defects happen. Nikon will certainly fix it for free.

Comment: yes i think thats not the problem.i have 2 years warranty.

Comment: it just drives me mad because it supposed to be new.

Comment: It's part of the modern manufacturing economy. It would be possible to make sure each camera was flawless, but the individual testing required would drive the price up to at least several times what you paid for it. Pushing the final testing to the consumer sucks when you end up the loser of the quality control lottery, but overall it is a much more efficient system.

Comment: Or depending on where you are, return it to the retailer as "not fit for purpose". This would certainly be valid in the UK, where your contract is with the retailer, not the manufacturer. I make no comment about other jurisdictions.

Comment: Since the camera worked for the first little while (and the problem is more likely to be a ribbon cable connection that wasn't as secure as it could have been than anything else), it's unlikely that factory QA would have picked it up. Cleaning off the fingerprints, etc., is likely to take longer than the actual repair, testing and packaging required to make this a refurbished item. (Doesn't keep it from being highly annoying though, and exchange is still the best option.)